# Convergence of sequence in locally convex topological vector space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a locally convex t.v.s. and
> $$
> (x_n) \subseteq X, \ (x_n) \rightarrow 0.
> $$
>
> Prove that
> $$
> y_n = \displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j \rightarrow 0.
> $$

I try to prove that for every $U \in \mathcal{N}_0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for any $n \geq n_0 \implies y_n \in U$. But I can't do it using the definition of a locally convex t.v.s.

Thanks for any help / advice / hint.

Comment: Why voted close though?

Comment: Hint: Easiest way is to prove through the family of seminorms

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ be an absolutely convex neighborhood of zero in $X$. There exists $N \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $x_n \in U/2$ for $n \ge N$. Let $m \in \mathbb N$ be s.t. $x_1 + \dots + x_{N-1} \in m U$. Then,
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} x_k + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=N}^n x_k \in \frac{m}{n} U + \frac{n - N+1}{2n} U.$$
Thus, for $n > 2m$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \in U.
$$

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Secondly, where did you use that the set $U$ is convex? Because I can only see the balanced property.

Comment: The convexity is used in the form $aU + bU \subset (a+b)U$ for $a,b > 0$.

Comment: That is true because $U$ is convex? Because for an abstract set $2U \subseteq U + U$.

Comment: That is true for the set of rationals $\mathbb Q$ (i.e. $2\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q + \mathbb Q$). Howewer, $a\mathbb Q + b\mathbb Q \not\subset (a+b)\mathbb Q$ for arbitrary $a,b >0$ (for example, $a = \pi$, $b = 4 - \pi$). Thus, you  can't omit the convexity in the proof.

Comment: Thank you. As an example I had in mind the set $\{ 1,2 \}$.